# Session Null when using apache

Tags: java, apache, session, tomcat

Am using Apache as a web server and Tomcat as Application server.
When i directly connect my application to tomcat without redirecting from apache everything works fine.

Once when i redirect through apache  Am getting  null Session.

In some cases it passing **jsessionid** in url and working perfect *Eg:wherever am using C:URL tag.*
Instead of that url for all the request am getting only null session.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the same request hitting the both servers ?

Comment: Are you redirecting directly with mod_redirect, making a http proxy with (mod_proxy) or using AJP (mod_proxy_ajp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not Tomcat Guru but what I know, is during redirection set flag to use redirection with Cookies. If no, you get new session ID or null.

Some applications like CURL have this flag disabled by default, suppose Apache - the same.

Hope it will help you

Comment: I think I'm experiencing the same problem. What did you change?